# ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Python 2.7 with Tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

Trying to enable tensorflow-gpu over python2.7 after installing Nvidia Quadro M4000. I got the below error message:
Strange thing is that it's complaining about libcudnn.so.5, but I have libcudnn.so.7 in /usr/local/cuda/lib64

Thanks for any suggestions!

> ~$ python
>   Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
>   [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
>   Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>
> > import tensorflow as tf
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "", line 1, in 
> >       File "/usr/local/google/home/hjchai/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
> >         from tensorflow.python import *
> >       File "/usr/local/google/home/hjchai/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
> >         from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
> >       File "/usr/local/google/home/hjchai/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in 
> >         raise ImportError(msg)
> >     ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "/usr/local/google/home/hjchai/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in 
> >         from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> >       File "/usr/local/google/home/hjchai/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
> >         _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> >       File "/usr/local/google/home/hjchai/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> >         _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
> >     ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating with my own solution.
It turns out I installed cudnn7.0 rather than cudnn5.1. 
Problem solved after I install the cudnn5.1. 
cheers!